# Denoise function in Rice Wavelet Toolbox R package

Tags: r, wavelet

The documentation for the `denoise`function in the `rwt` package is not so clear , does anybody know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- sig <- makesig(SIGNAL.DOPPLER)
- h <- daubcqf(6)
- r1 <- denoise.dwt(sig$x, h$h.0)
- opts <- r1$option
- opts <- opts[-7]
- opts$threshold.type <- 1
- opts <- r1$option